# PHP class to find value in array from session

Tags: php, class

I am trying to make a simple class that I can use to check if a value exists within an array. There is a session that contains multiple `tool` values. I am trying to pass the `toolID` to this function as well as a `key` and see if that value exists.

**Session Data:**

```
Array
(
    [keyring] => Array
        (
            [tool] => Array
                (
                    [toolID] => 1859
                    [keys] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 49
                            [1] => 96
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

---

```
class Keyring
{

    public function checkKey($key, $toolID){
        $keyring = $_SESSION['keyring'];
        if(isset($keyring)){
            foreach($keyring['tool'] as $k => $v) {
                if($k == 'toolID' && $v == $toolID){
                    if (in_array($key, $k->keys)){
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

} 

$keyring = new Keyring();
print_r($keyring->checkKey(49, 1859));
```

In this example, I am trying to see if key `49` exists in the session for tool `1859`.

I am getting the following error : `Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in`.

Is there a better approach for this? All I am looking for is a `true`/`false` as to whether that key exists in the `keys` array for the specified tool.

Comment: `$k->keys` should be `$keyring['tool']['keys']`

Comment: Or just, use `$v` checking if `$v` is an array, or; checking `$k` === 'keys'

Answer (score 0):

For my code to work for you may need to change your array a bit or change the code a bit, but rather then looping through a bunch of keys trying to find the right one we are just looking for the keys in the array if they are not set, then return false, or if we find keyring - tools - $tool_id - key_{$key_id} we are just going to return that value, if key_49 = false the function returns false.  This should be a tad bit quicker to run on the server for you.

```
function has_keyring($tool_id, $key_id)
{
    //Just to keep the code tidy let's store the tools key in $tool variable
    $tool = $_SESSION['keyring']['tools'];
    if(isset($tool[$tool_id]) && isset($tool[$tool_id]["key_{$key_id}"]))
         return $tool[$tool_id]["key_{$key_id}"];
    return false;
}
```